# Performance optimization in function for datastructure mapping

Tags: performance, perl

I want to optimize a Perl function which is frequently used in my application. The function creates a special datastructure from the results of `DBI::fetchall_arrayref` which looks like:

```
$columns = ['COLNAME_1','COLNAME_2','COLNAME_3']
$rows    = [ ['row_1_col_1', 'row_1_col_2', 'row_1_col_3'],
             ['row_2_col_1', 'row_2_col_2', 'row_2_col_3'],
             ['row_3_col_1', 'row_3_col_2', 'row_3_col_3']
];
```

The new datastructure must contain the data in the following form (all row-values for every column in a single arrayref)

```
$retval = { 
    row_count => 3,
    col_count => 3,
    COLNAME_1 => ['row_1_col_1', 'row_2_col_1', 'row_3_col_1' ],
    COLNAME_2 => ['row_1_col_2', 'row_2_col_2', 'row_3_col_2' ],
    COLNAME_3 => ['row_1_col_3', 'row_2_col_3', 'row_3_col_3' ]
}
```

The new datastructure is a Hash of Arrays and is used in the whole application. I cannot change the format (its too frequently used). I wrote a function for this conversion. I've already done some some performance optimization after profiling my application. But it's not enough. Now the function looks like:

```
sub reorganize($$) {
    my ($self,$columns,$rows) = @_;
    my $col_count = scalar(@$columns);
    my $row_count = scalar(@$rows);
    my $col_index = 0;
    my $row_index = 0;
    my $retval = {  # new datastructure
        row_count   => $row_count,
        col_count   => $col_count    
    };

    # iterate through all columns
    for($col_index=0; $col_index<$col_count; $col_index++) {
        # create a arrayref for all row-values of the current column
        # set it to the correct size and assign all values to this arrayref
        my $tmp = [];
        $#{$tmp} = $row_count-1;    # set size of array to the number of rows

        # iterate through all rows
        for($row_index=0; $row_index<$row_count; $row_index++) {      
            # assign values to arrayref (which has the correct size) instead of a "slow" push
            $tmp->[$row_index] = $rows->[$row_index][$col_index];            
        }
        # Assign the arrayref to the hash. The hash-key is the name of the column
        $retval->{$columns->[$col_index]} = $tmp;
    }
    return $retval;
}
```

My Question:

Is there a way to further optimize this function (maybe using $*[...])?  I found some hints [here](http://de.slideshare.net/perrin_harkins/top-10-perl-performance-tips-11845463) at page 18 and 19, but I don't have any experience in using $* in different contexts.

I have to say that the function listed above is the best I can do. There may be other ways to do some optimization which I have never heard of.

Comment: Just a note: It seems (`$self`) you are using the subroutine as a method. You can remove the prototypes `($$)` as they are ignored in method calls anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is about 35% faster (measured with [Benchmark](http://p3rl.org/Benchmark)). The tricks:

- no anonymous array created for `$tmp`.
- explicit `return` removed.
- variables created in place where their value is needed.

Some of the tricks added just a 3%, the first one seemed the most important. YMMV.

I experimented with `$_` and `map`s, too, but it seems the plain old C-style loop is the fastest.

```
sub faster {
    my ($self, $columns, $rows) = @_;
    my $retval = {
        row_count   => my $row_count = @$rows,
        col_count   => my $col_count = @$columns,
    };
    for (my $col_index = 0 ; $col_index < $col_count ; $col_index++) {
        my $tmp;
        for (my $row_index = 0 ; $row_index < $row_count ; $row_index++) {
            $tmp->[$row_index] = $rows->[$row_index][$col_index];
        }
        $retval->{$columns->[$col_index]} = $tmp;
    }
    $retval
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. The first and second tricks are really interesting and from a c-style point of view very strange. i will try it with NYTProf asap.

Comment: @some_coder: Forget the C-style point of view when optimizing Perl :-)

Comment: In my benchmark (yay!) I've observed foreach loop was faster (and, what's even more important, more readable), so please change C-style fors to `for my $col_index (0 .. $col_count - 1)`.

Comment: @Xaerxess: In my Benchmark, switching to this style loop was slower.

Comment: @choroba I guess it depends on how many iterations you're doing - see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Xaerxess/9486043), for-c outperforms foreach only up to 4-8 elements to iterate over. Still, in terms of readability, foreach wins, and that said I wish I'd never have to optimize fors.